# CSS color is overridden by link

Tags: c#, css, razor

I'm using Razor in a C# MVC website to add a feature to the existing site.

I'm trying to specify the color of my html text using CSS. I have successfully done this in another area of the site using `class` specifiers and it worked great. However, I am now trying to change the color of a link (C# Hml.ActionLink()) and my CSS is being overridden by another link style (verified using Chrome Developer Tools) even when using `!important`.

This link style seems to have a large scope and thus I can't change it without affecting other areas of the site.

I've tried setting the `color` attribute as well as `text-decoration-color` and have tried `!important` on both.

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to CSS btw.

Oh, and I *can* see that my CSS changes are actually being used in Chrome Developer Tools, but they're just being overridden (so class stuff is correct).

Razor code:

```
<div id="Project">
    @foreach (string name in Model.Foo)
     {
        string className = Model.Bar.Contains(name) ? "changed" : "unchanged";
        <p class=@className>@Html.ActionLink(foo)</p>
     }
</div>
```

CSS code (have tried variations of the below):

```
.changed {
    color: red !important;
}

.unchanged {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: You're doing the changes on the <p>, maybe there's a color on the <a>. The <a> will take prority in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS selectors to specify the inner element

```
.changed a {...}
.unchanged a {...}
```

You may also be more specific like this

```
.changed > a {...}
.unchanged > a {...}
```

The > means that your anchor must be a direct decendant of the element of class changes / unchanged.

---

Unreleated to your problem but I wanted to point it out:

```
<p class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(foo)</p>
```

instead of

```
<p class=@className>@Html.ActionLink(foo)</p>
```

(Still works in your situation but you will run in some weird problems one day)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the selectors to increase specificty,

```
.changed a {
    color: red !important;
}

.unchanged a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you describe you want to change the link color and not the p tag
so try this

```
.changed a{
    color: red !important;
}

.unchanged a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the CSS to the anchor tag, not the paragraph tag, try this:

```
.changed a {
    color: red !important;
}

.unchanged a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: blue !important;
}
```